# Query SQL with "childs"

Tags: sql, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm a newbie with SQL and I was wondering if something like what I'm going to show will be possible to do.

I have a table like this :

```
    A    B    C    D
-------------------------
    1              ONE
         1    P
         1    PF
    2              TWO
         2    PF
    3              THREE
         3    P
         3    P
         3    P
         3    P
    4              FOUR
         4    PF
         4    PF
    5              FIVE
         5    P
```

I would like to do a query to extract the fields in column "A" which doesn't have a "PF" in column "C" with the same number. I.e.:

```
    A    B    C    D
-------------------------
    3              THREE
         3    P
         3    P
         3    P
         3    P
    5              FIVE
         5    P
```

I'm using Python 2.7 and SQLite 3

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the empty values are NULL, you can use [coalesce()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce) to get the parent ID in each row:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE COALESCE(A, B) NOT IN (SELECT B
                             FROM MyTable
                             WHERE C = 'PF');
```

Answer (score -1):

I created the below table and inserted the records

```
  create table abcd ( a integer, b integer, c varchar(10), d varchar(100) );
  insert into abcd values (1,null,null,'ONE');
  insert into abcd values (null,1,'P',null);
  insert into abcd values (null, 1,'PF',null);
  insert into abcd values (2,null,null,'TWO')
  insert into abcd values (null,2,'PF',null);
  insert into abcd values (3,null,null,'THREE');
  insert into abcd values (null,3,'P',null);
  insert into abcd values (null,3,'P',null);
  insert into abcd values (null,3,'P',null);
  insert into abcd values (null,3,'P',null);
  insert into abcd values (4,null,null,'FOUR');
  insert into abcd values (null,4,'PF',null);
  insert into abcd values (null,4,'PF',null);
  insert into abcd values (5,null,null,'FIVE');
  insert into abcd values (null,5,'P',null);

  select * from abcd;
```

The below query gives the result set

```
   with temp as 
   (
         SELECT ISNULL(a, (SELECT TOP 1 a FROM abcd 
         WHERE a = t.b 
         AND a IS NOT NULL 
         ORDER BY d DESC)) as a , b,c,d
         FROM  abcd t
    ),
  flag as 
   (
    select a,b,c,d,case when c='PF' then 1 else 0 end as flag 
    from temp
    where c is not null 
   )
 select * from temp  
 where a in (select distinct a from flag where c <> 'PF'
 and a not in ( select a from flag where flag=1))
```